# Upside of the Third Reich

Tags: government, history

I'm listening to a podcast by Dan Carlin, and he asked the listener to imagine the reaction of society to a book called "The Upsides of the Third Reich." Of course people could protest such a book, and writing one may be culturally insensitive, 500 years from now such a writing may be accepted... 
My question is: What are the positives that came from WW2, more specifically Hitler's actions. What would we title some of these chapters, in this imaginary book?

Comment: This appears to be a question about real, actual history and the events that unfolded therein, and should be on [History SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/), rather than WB.

Comment: Woops sorry, I'm new at this, I'll delete

Comment: You can simply flag it for the moderators to move it to the other SE.

Comment: The gimme answer would be rocketry technology and general advancements in aeronautics.

Comment: @Wingman417 True. I forgot about that. And Jerry cans. What did the Romans ever do for us?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think as it is, this would be rejected on [history.se] as either primarily opinion-based, or too broad. I'm putting it on hold here, but if you can [edit] the question to meet their standards, then you can flag it again after editing and we can migrate it at that point. See [the History SE on-topic page](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and make sure to allow for answers, ideally a single answer, which are authoritative and can be backed up by verifiable fact, rather than being speculative.

Comment: The New Order, like most authoritarian regimes, has only one advantage over market based Liberal orders (Liberal as in individual freedom, unfettered property rights and rule of law), in that it can allocate resources much more quickly to whatever the rulers want. If the rulers choose well (or start from a very low state, such as the collapsed German economy), then initially this looks better than markets, but eventually poor choices and resource allocation crash the system.

Comment: Not to mention Hitler's [speed psychosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodor_Morell) and rampant megalomania assisting the inevitable downfall of the Reich.

Comment: There's the curious idea today that if we say someone is evil, we don't dare attribute ANY positive qualities to him. I once commented somewhere that Hitler was a brilliant speaker and politician. I got a huge wave of criticism: How dare I say anything positive about Hitler! But my statement was surely true, as proven by the way he got so many people to follow him. If Hitler had been an incompetent politician, he never would have been able to reach a position where he could do so much harm. He would have just been that annoying guy at the bar who was always going on and on about the Jews.

Comment: and Hitler most certain did many things to improve the lot of the common German.  As I sort through the information available though, most of the good he did was intended to "win the masses" so he could collect more power.  In many ways he didn't seem to actually care much about "the common man" other than to get his vote.  As time went by, he seemed less and less interested.

Answer (score 2):

As distasteful as it is for me to say it, there were some things that the Third Reich pulled off successfully, although at GREAT expense of human life, morality, and truth.

After the Great Depression in 1929, Germany was in chaos. They'd lost the first World War, and massive reparations payments that they couldn't hope to make to the winners, and the economy was ruined.

Currency was devalued to the point that to buy food, you'd need a wheelbarrow to carry all the worthless currency required to buy a loaf of bread.

That all changed when the Nazis pushed their way into power (that in itself is a story of violence, lies, betrayal and political backstabbing). Over time, it all turned around.

The really nasty thing is that to this day, people are still debating whether to use the data and research findings that were meticulously recorded by such characters as [Dr. Josef Mengele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Mengele). He (and others) conducted medical experiments on live humans in concentration camps as if they were lab rats.

I won't go into which chapters you'd write for this book, it's already messing with my sense of right and wrong writing this much.

But one thing I will say is that IBM would probably not have been able to advance the electronic computer as much as they have done, without having had the Nazis as their biggest customers before (and even during) the war.

The cross indexing tabulating machines that the Nazis used for their comprehensive census operations were [sold and maintained by IBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_and_the_Holocaust).

These machines were instrumental in allowing the Nazis to separate out anybody they deemed to be an undesirable.

And that sophisticated technology was one of the stepping stones to the modern computer.